# Save file object to internal storage as image

Tags: android, android-file, loopj

I am downloading image via a URL using loopj library https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http. In response I get image as File object. I want to store this image as .jpg to my internal storage and get the path of that image. Can anyone please help me regarding this? Or suggest me any other library or the code through which I can achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
try {
        File imgFile = null; //File you received from loopj
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imgFile);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("yourPath.jpg"));
        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) imgFile.length()];
        fis.read(fileContent);
        fos.write(fileContent);
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```